# Multi-threading and constructor completeness

Tags: c#, multithreading, constructor

The other day I stumbled upon a `NullReferenceException` which I thought was totally impossible. I have small class which contains a dictionary, and that dictionary is instantiated in the constructor:

```
public MyClass
{
    protected readonly Dictionary<string, ISomething> _MyList;
    public MyClass()
    {
        _MyList = new List<ISomething>();
    }
    public void Add(string name, ISomething something)
    {
        _MyList.Add(name, something);
    }
}
```

Hard to believe but true, the exception occurred at `_MyList.Add`. When I run that in the debugger, it showed that `_MyList` already contained one item, but still the exception occurred - in another thread. Note: there is no code which sets `_MyList` to `null`. `protected` is for use in some test setups only.

`MyClass` gets instantiated at startup. The configuration engine instantiates many objects and wires them up.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
ISomething some1 = new ...();
some1.Inject(myClass);
ISomething some2 = new ...();
some2.Inject(myClass);
```

Later on, `Start()` is called on the top level object which propagates down in multiple threads. There, `some1` and `some2` register with `myClass` by calling `Add`. While `some1` does that in the same thread all those objects were created, `some2` does it in a different thread. And it is `some2`'s call to `Add` which causes the `NullReferenceException` (the log files show thread-ids).

My impression is that there is some threading issue. Somehow on multi-core machines, there are different "copies" of `myClass` for different threads (cores), one is completely constructed, the other one is not.

I could solve the problem by replacing `Dictionary` by `ConcurrentDictionary`.

I'd like to get a better understanding of:

- how the `NullReferenceException` could happen, and
- how `ConcurrentDictionary` resolves this issue

Edit:
My first impression - that _MyList was null - was likely wrong. Rather, the exception happens inside the Dictionary: e.g it contains two arrays `buckets` and `entries` which get initialized at the first call to `Add`. And here, the race happens, one thread starting the initialization, while the other assumes that initialization was complete.

Hence, my original conclusion of some register caching causing the issues in a multi-threaded environment and some "magic" of ConcurrentDictionary somehow implicitly being "volatile" was wrong - the second part of my question has no meaning any more.

Comment: So what is the question ? As for the moment you've only given us an explanation on how multi-threading works and what issues are there. Certainly, if we use thread-unsafe collection in a multi-thread environment it will most likely cause issues.

Comment: " Somehow on multi-core machines, there are different "copies" of myClass" No.

Comment: Also, can you provide an example of this (sometimes) happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how the NullReferenceException could happen

The dictionary does not know how much data will be stored in it, so as you add items it must resize itself. This resize operation takes time, if two threads both detect that extra room is needed they will both try and perform the resize at the same time. The "looser" of this race condition will get his data written to a copy of the data that is overwritten by the "winner", this can cause the spot that the looser wrote to look like a valid location in the internal array but actually it holds uninitialized data. When you try to access this uninitialized data it throws the `NullReferenceException`. (Note: This resize race is only one of many race conditions that can happen if multiple threads try to write to a dictionary at the same  time)

> how ConcurrentDictionary resolves this issue

Any action that can result in a race condition is checked internally to see if the thread was the looser or not. If it was it throws away the work it did and re-tries to insert the data again until it is successful. Once successful the function call returns.

Here is a copy [from the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,bc495056297a0851) of the logic that goes in to that checking.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Shared internal implementation for inserts and updates.
        /// If key exists, we always return false; and if updateIfExists == true we force update with value;
        /// If key doesn't exist, we always add value and return true;
        /// </summary>
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Concurrency", "CA8001", Justification = "Reviewed for thread safety")]
        private bool TryAddInternal(TKey key, TValue value, bool updateIfExists, bool acquireLock, out TValue resultingValue)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int bucketNo, lockNo;
                int hashcode;

                Tables tables = m_tables;
                IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = tables.m_comparer;
                hashcode = comparer.GetHashCode(key);
                GetBucketAndLockNo(hashcode, out bucketNo, out lockNo, tables.m_buckets.Length, tables.m_locks.Length);

                bool resizeDesired = false;
                bool lockTaken = false;
#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
#if !FEATURE_CORECLR                
                bool resizeDueToCollisions = false;
#endif // !FEATURE_CORECLR
#endif

                try
                {
                    if (acquireLock)
                        Monitor.Enter(tables.m_locks[lockNo], ref lockTaken);

                    // If the table just got resized, we may not be holding the right lock, and must retry.
                    // This should be a rare occurence.
                    if (tables != m_tables)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
#if !FEATURE_CORECLR
                    int collisionCount = 0;
#endif // !FEATURE_CORECLR
#endif

                    // Try to find this key in the bucket
                    Node prev = null;
                    for (Node node = tables.m_buckets[bucketNo]; node != null; node = node.m_next)
                    {
                        Assert((prev == null && node == tables.m_buckets[bucketNo]) || prev.m_next == node);
                        if (comparer.Equals(node.m_key, key))
                        {
                            // The key was found in the dictionary. If updates are allowed, update the value for that key.
                            // We need to create a new node for the update, in order to support TValue types that cannot
                            // be written atomically, since lock-free reads may be happening concurrently.
                            if (updateIfExists)
                            {
                                if (s_isValueWriteAtomic)
                                {
                                    node.m_value = value;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Node newNode = new Node(node.m_key, value, hashcode, node.m_next);
                                    if (prev == null)
                                    {
                                        tables.m_buckets[bucketNo] = newNode;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        prev.m_next = newNode;
                                    }
                                }
                                resultingValue = value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                resultingValue = node.m_value;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                        prev = node;

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
#if !FEATURE_CORECLR
                        collisionCount++;
#endif // !FEATURE_CORECLR
#endif
                    }

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
#if !FEATURE_CORECLR
                    if(collisionCount > HashHelpers.HashCollisionThreshold && HashHelpers.IsWellKnownEqualityComparer(comparer)) 
                    {
                        resizeDesired = true;
                        resizeDueToCollisions = true;
                    }
#endif // !FEATURE_CORECLR
#endif

                    // The key was not found in the bucket. Insert the key-value pair.
                    Volatile.Write<Node>(ref tables.m_buckets[bucketNo], new Node(key, value, hashcode, tables.m_buckets[bucketNo]));
                    checked
                    {
                        tables.m_countPerLock[lockNo]++;
                    }

                    //
                    // If the number of elements guarded by this lock has exceeded the budget, resize the bucket table.
                    // It is also possible that GrowTable will increase the budget but won't resize the bucket table.
                    // That happens if the bucket table is found to be poorly utilized due to a bad hash function.
                    //
                    if (tables.m_countPerLock[lockNo] > m_budget)
                    {
                        resizeDesired = true;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (lockTaken)
                        Monitor.Exit(tables.m_locks[lockNo]);
                }

                //
                // The fact that we got here means that we just performed an insertion. If necessary, we will grow the table.
                //
                // Concurrency notes:
                // - Notice that we are not holding any locks at when calling GrowTable. This is necessary to prevent deadlocks.
                // - As a result, it is possible that GrowTable will be called unnecessarily. But, GrowTable will obtain lock 0
                //   and then verify that the table we passed to it as the argument is still the current table.
                //
                if (resizeDesired)
                {
#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
#if !FEATURE_CORECLR
                    if (resizeDueToCollisions)
                    {
                        GrowTable(tables, (IEqualityComparer<TKey>)HashHelpers.GetRandomizedEqualityComparer(comparer), true, m_keyRehashCount);
                    }
                    else
#endif // !FEATURE_CORECLR
                    {
                        GrowTable(tables, tables.m_comparer, false, m_keyRehashCount);
                    }
#else
                    GrowTable(tables, tables.m_comparer, false, m_keyRehashCount);
#endif
                }

                resultingValue = value;
                return true;
            }
        }
```

In comparison, here is the code for a [normal dictionary's version](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs.html#fd1acf96113fbda9) of the same function.

```
        private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add) {

            if( key == null ) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
            }

            if (buckets == null) Initialize(0);
            int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
            int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
            int collisionCount = 0;
#endif

            for (int i = buckets[targetBucket]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
                if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) {
                    if (add) { 
                        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Argument_AddingDuplicate);
                    }
                    entries[i].value = value;
                    version++;
                    return;
                } 

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING
                collisionCount++;
#endif
            }
            int index;
            if (freeCount > 0) {
                index = freeList;
                freeList = entries[index].next;
                freeCount--;
            }
            else {
                if (count == entries.Length)
                {
                    Resize();
                    targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
                }
                index = count;
                count++;
            }

            entries[index].hashCode = hashCode;
            entries[index].next = buckets[targetBucket];
            entries[index].key = key;
            entries[index].value = value;
            buckets[targetBucket] = index;
            version++;

#if FEATURE_RANDOMIZED_STRING_HASHING

#if FEATURE_CORECLR
            // In case we hit the collision threshold we'll need to switch to the comparer which is using randomized string hashing
            // in this case will be EqualityComparer<string>.Default.
            // Note, randomized string hashing is turned on by default on coreclr so EqualityComparer<string>.Default will 
            // be using randomized string hashing

            if (collisionCount > HashHelpers.HashCollisionThreshold && comparer == NonRandomizedStringEqualityComparer.Default) 
            {
                comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>) EqualityComparer<string>.Default;
                Resize(entries.Length, true);
            }
#else
            if(collisionCount > HashHelpers.HashCollisionThreshold && HashHelpers.IsWellKnownEqualityComparer(comparer)) 
            {
                comparer = (IEqualityComparer<TKey>) HashHelpers.GetRandomizedEqualityComparer(comparer);
                Resize(entries.Length, true);
            }
#endif // FEATURE_CORECLR

#endif

        }
```

Comment: That is you suggest that the constructor of `MyClass` was completed anyway. Only a `Resize` caused by `Add` caused an invalid Dictionary, which resulted in the NullReferenceException. Interesting point which I will read up.

Comment: There are many other things that can cause this too. But calling Add while doing any other operation (Even just doing a read) is the most common cause for this to happen.

Comment: Currently, my impression is that `if (buckets == null) Initialize(0);` is the key to understanding this behavior. The ctor of Dictionary calls Initialize only when a capacity is given. Hence, in my example both `buckets` and `entries` are null at the first call to `Add`. While the first call causes a call to Initialize, the second call will find `buckets` existing, but `entries`may still be null => exception.

Comment: You must also consider the calls to `Resize()`, a concurrent read or write during a `Resize()` can cause it to throw a exception too. Those resizes will happen every time `count == entries.Length`. Also two people overwriting eachother in the block of code that starts with `entries[index].hashCode = hashCode;` could cause this behavior too.